# How do i detect if a dummy command has a certain score in 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to figure out recently how to test if a team and or player has a certain score like 3 or 5 or something. If someone could tell me how that would be great!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: yes, i have, and i honestly don't know how to specify it any better, i'm kind of crappy with words....

Comment: I'm not really seeing any evidence of effort here.  It's a good idea to show us what you've tried.  Doesn't need to be perfect, but we like to see you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I found a question on minecraft forums very similar to yours, so i have left a link to it and here is one of the best answers i found

use a testfor, something like this
/testfor @a[score_TIMER_min=100]

This will need to be in the commandblock and an output of a comparator. Last you will need a clock to keep it checking when this statement is true.

So the code checks when @a, anyone, has a minimum timer score of 100. If the requirement is meet, then the command block will output a redstone signal strength of 1 through the comparator.

link:http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/348673-detect-a-certian-player-score-with-command-blocks

Comment: Thx, i really appreciate it :)